# : after variables in pascal

Tags: variables, pascal

I know that by using 0:3 in this code in Pascal will put 3 decimal places to the result

```
var a,b:real;

begin
a:=23;
b:=7;
writeln(a/b:0:3);

readln;
end.
```

What I would like to know is if anyone has a source to learn what this : will do with other variables or if adding for example 0:3:4 will make a difference. Basically what : can do to a variable

Comment: The : doesn't do anything to the variable, it only affects how a string representation of the variable is rendered in a write or writeln operation.

Comment: Read what the doc's are saying: [Write Description](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Write#Description)

Answer (score 2):

For the *exact* definition of *`write` parameters* take a look at [ISO standards 7185 and 10206](https://web.archive.org/web/20210424001153/http://standardpascal.org/standards.html), “Standard Pascal” and “Extended Pascal” respectively. These references are useless though if your compiler’s documentation does not make a statement regarding compliance with them. Other compilers have their own non-standard extensions, so the only *reliable* source of reference is your compiler’s documentation or even its source code if available.

> […] what this : will do with other variables […] Basically what : can do to a variable

As [MartynA already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263986/after-variables-in-pascal#comment124207393_70263986) this language is imprecise: The variables’ *values* are only *read* by `write`/`writeLn`/`writeStr`, thus leaving them unmodified.

> […] if adding for example 0:3:4 will make a difference.

To my knowledge a *third* write parameter is/was only allowed in PXSC, Pascal eXtensions for Scientific Computing. In this case the third parameter would indicate for the rounding mode (nonexistent or `0`: closest printable number; greater than zero: round up; less than zero: round down).